# What is the difference between 5 and [5] in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

They seem to be exactly the same, like:

```
>> v1 = [5];
>> v2 = 5;
>> isequal(v1, v2)
ans = 
      1
>> [5] * [1,2,3]
ans = 
       5   10   15
>> v1(1)
ans = 
      5
>> v2(1)
ans = 
      5
```

Is there any differenceI should be aware of?

Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

> Is there any difference I should be aware of?

No

Answer (score 4):

Although there is no significant difference, there is a difference.

`v1=5;` is creating a variable called `v1` that has a value of 5.

`v1=[5];` is defining a matrix/scalar with the value of 5; then it is concatenating that matrix with nothing - concatenation is the operation performed by the square brackets, and is why you do need them to define `[1,2,3]` - and then the result is assigned to the variable `v1`.  So using the square brackets performs an additional operation.

This is why if you write your code in the editor you'll receive an m-lint message saying

> The use of brackets [] is unnecessary.  Use parenthesis to group, if needed.

Answer (score 4):

There is no difference between `[5]` and `5`. But in general there may be a difference between an expression `[f]` and `f`, where `f` is some expression. Here is an example:

`c = {10,20,30,40,50,60};
x = c{1:3}
y = [c{1:3}]`

Here, `c` is a cell array, so the operation `c{1:3}` returns all objects in places 1 to 3 of `c` as a **comma-separated list**, in other words it returns `10,20,30`. It *does not* return the array `[10,20,30]`. So, the command `x = c{1:3}` is equivalent to `x=10,20,30`, which is equivalent to assigning `x` the value `10`, and then doing nothing with the literals `20` and `30`. On the other hand, the command `y = [c{1:3}]` groups the comma-separated list between brackets `[]`, so it is equivalent to `y=[10,20,30]`. To conclude, `x` will have the value `10` while `y` will have the value `[10,20,30]`.